# How do I set the associated application for files with no extension in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-7

> #### Already Migrated to Super User:
>
> [How to set the default program for opening files without an extension in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/13653/how-to-set-the-default-program-for-opening-files-without-an-extension-in-windows)

I am running Windows 7 x64 and when double clicking on a file with no extension, I would like it to automatically open in notepad rather than bring up the "Open with" window.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: @Steve: I think you mean superuser.

Comment: yeah, thanks guys, found it at: http://superuser.com/questions/13653/how-to-set-the-default-program-for-opening-files-without-an-extension-in-windows